# Read a .txt file inside documents directory

Tags: ios, nsdocumentdirectory

How can I read a .txt file inside documents directory? Can you show me code?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"txtFile.txt"];
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

Comment: As simple and easy as the snippet is, I would recommend adding some context or code comments

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `NSFileHandle` for writing data in file and save to document directory:
You can follow: [NSFileHandle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44773697/8023444)